# Invisible line in featured questions

Tags: bug, questions, specific-question

My question is not really important but it's about some little aspect of beauty:

[image]

If we have any featured questions there are no line under it's blank. Is it a bug?

P.S. I'm using Mozilla Firefox

Comment: I'm using Mozilla, so it's browser-depended.

Comment: Page layout is write once, debug forever.  Press Ctrl-+ to zoom in and see the issue disappear.  SO devs get nice big monitors, it is a company perk.

Comment: [I can recreate also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337283/minor-ui-bug-missing-border-on-featured-questions-tab) on Chrome. 
We had similar issues on our web site when using border widths of < 1px. Looking at the CSS briefly I can't spot the issue. Seems to be an issue when zoomed out below 100% (I use 90% zoom)