# Minor UI bug, missing border on Featured questions tab

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

Seems to be a minor UI bug on the home page (note the missing `border-bottom` below "featured"):

[image]

hover (border re-appears):

[image]

Seen on Chrome 54.0.2840.87 m

Comment: this wasn't an issue for me yesterday though, which seems a little strange if that is a duplicate

Comment: It might be accidentally fixed but now resurfaced. Having those two posts at least gives the devs enough guidance where to look for / come up with something that breaks less easy.

Comment: Does seem to be a dupe. Like that question if I zoom out the border appears. I've seen this in our design if you have a border of < 1px

Comment: Does the bug shows when zoomed at 100%? Because SE claims they don't support zooming but if this glitch is present at 100% it is a genuine bug.

Comment: No, I typically have 90% zoom. My work monitor is not the highest res...

Comment: Ok, fair enough. *orders new monitor for @Liam*